# Disproof of an attempted disproof of the pythagorean theorem because of recursively defined path

Tags: geometry

Here is a video that attempts to state that the Pythagorean theorem is wrong:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rRaAgjU5kw

I know he must be making an incorrect assumption but I have gotten a lot of contesting reasons from other forums. So could someone provide a clear answer as to what is wrong with this?

Comment: The taxicab geometry distance run in Manhattan streets never equals the direct distance as the crow flies.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These curves used to be called pathological curves, now they are called fractal curves.

As you go to infinity, the stairwell curve never actually becomes a straight line, that is, it never becomes smooth. Because it's not really a straight line, the pythagorean theorem does not apply. The actual definition of smooth requires calculus and is complicated. There are even different degrees of smoothness.

Fractal curves are not smooth at all. They might look smooth, but that is a problem with the way our eyes and brains work and the actual practical matters involved in the way we graph functions.

Let't take a more technical look at this stair curve approximation to the diagonal. We need to show why, even after an infinite number of iterations, the resulting curve is not a straight line.

[image: First four iterations of the stair curve]

Just to make this discussion easier, let's assume that we have put a ruler against the diagonal so that the coordinate of the first point is $0_2 = \dfrac 01$ and the coordinate of the last point is $0.1_2 = \dfrac 12$.

The image above shows the first four iterations of the stair curve. The points that make of the stair curve are counted in base two from $0.0_2$ to $0.1_2$ (the radix is not shown) in increments of $2^{-n}$.

This implies that, even when we go to infinity, the number of points of the stair curve that are actually on the diagonal will be countable. Hence, even when we go to infinity, the stair curve will be different from the diagonal.

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n \ne \overline{A_0A_{\frac 12}} $$

Comment: Thank you. I had someone with higher credentials than I claim that it was not a fractal so I tried another approach. This was my original answer so I'm feeling a little vindicated ^___^

Comment: But the fallacy can be presented with arbitrarily smooth curves, so I don't think focusing on "fractal curves" and lack of smoothness is going to give the best insight.

Comment: Of course we know the many traditional proofs are correct but I think this is interesting. A just for fun kind of thing.

Comment: @hardmath The definition of the arc length generally requires smoothness. The limit of the stairwell curve is nowhere differentiable. To tell you the truth. Insight wasn't what I was attempting to do here.

Comment: You could smooth it out, but then the method would be replaced by one that flattens the waves in between and the sequence of wavy curves would converge to a straight line and be of the same distance as the hypotenuse.

Comment: If you used waves it would be a Taylor series and the length would contract to the hypotenuse correct? The lack of smoothness is what causes the degeneracy.

Comment: Archimedes approximated the circumference of a circle with a polygon, e.g. a less smooth curve.  In any case I again point out that without the Pythagorean Theorem to build on, we get nowhere with lengths of smooth curves.

Comment: @hardmath -  On the contrary, the limit of the polygon is a smooth curve.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, a sum of the lengths of infinitesimal hypotenuses (hypotenii?) is needed to compute arc length. And that can only be done on smooth curves.

Comment: I apologise for not presenting this is the correct format earlier. I was trying to disprove it on my own and ask for a critique on it. I seemed to have gotten what I was looking for, at the cost of every point that I've earned (not much), but I'm happy I have a solid reason now. Much thanks to @StevenGregory for providing such a well made answer.

Comment: @JeffreyColeman - I first saw this when I was in high school and was terribly upset by it. This is a very big thing, if not resolved, then the (elementary calculus) definition of arc length is meaningless. It took me a lot of work to come to terms with why it doesn't work.